# how do I pop up an image automatically when a user go to my website home page using php?

Tags: php, image, popup

I want an image to automatically popup when someone goes to our website main page. User can close it by clicking on close button. when user clicks close then it's show normal home page. Can someone please show me how to do this using PHP? Thanks you!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and we can try to help you. Also, please correct the spelling errors to give more clarity.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

You can that by using javascript.

I think you may be need to show a notice or ad.
Then it is better to use css modal than popup new window.

See below

1. css modal - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   /* The Modal (background) */
   .modal {
       display: none; /* Hidden by default */
       position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
       z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
       padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%; /* Full width */
       height: 100%; /* Full height */
       overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
       background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
   }

   /* Modal Content */
   .modal-content {
       background-color: #fefefe;
       margin: auto;
       padding: 20px;
       border: 1px solid #888;
       width: 80%;
   }

   /* The Close Button */
   .close {
       color: #aaaaaa;
       float: right;
       font-size: 28px;
       font-weight: bold;
   }

   .close:hover,
   .close:focus {
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

   <h2>Modal Example</h2>

   <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
   <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

   <!-- The Modal -->
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">

     <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <span class="close">&times;</span>
       <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
     </div>

   </div>

   <script>
   // Get the modal
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

   // Get the button that opens the modal
   var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

   // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
   btn.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "block";
   }

   // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   span.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "none";
   }

   // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
           modal.style.display = "none";
       }
   }
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. open new window - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

   <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   <script>
   function myFunction() {
       window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
   }
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Please do not post answers that are _only_ a link to an external resource. If that link breaks, then your answer becomes invalid. Posting links to other resources is encouraged, but you should also include information in your post about relevant information from that external resource or otherwise. Please check out [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/360627) to learn more about why this is generally frowned upon and can be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can open model when document load.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Any Image
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/py9ajtkj/)

Comment: This requires [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which was not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: "of course"? But it isn't mentioned anywhere in your answer, or in the question.

Comment: You can check in jsfiddle, I have added external javascript.

Comment: Yes _I_ know that this requires bootstrap _just from looking at it_, my point is that it is not mentioned _in the answer_ or even _in the question_ meaning the OP may not have been looking for a framework solution.

Comment: ok I got your point. I will add it now. Thanks for suggestion. :)